# ReactJS Dynamically hiding and showing table column causes Invariant Violation

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a React component for a table. If the user is not me, then when I see that user's profile page, I only see the first three columns of the table. If the user is me, then I see four columns. However, dynamically changing the columns causes the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 3 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID `.0.1.1.0.0.1.0.0`.
```

I've looked around a lot and made sure that my table is encased with . How can I allow for this table flexibility in React?

My outer table shell looks like this:

```
var CategoriesTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var includeReps = false;
    var repsHeader = '';
    if (this.props.currentUser.username === this.props.user.username) {
      includeReps = true;
      repsHeader = <th>Reps</th>;
    }

  return (
    <div className="categoriesTable panel panel-default">
      <CategoriesHeader user={this.props.user} />
      <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Direct Rep</th>
            <th>Crowd Rep</th>
            {repsHeader}
          </tr>
          {this.props.user.categories.map(function(category) {
            return <CategoriesItem key={category.id} category={category.name} directRep={category.directScore} prevDirectRep={category.previousDirectScore} crowdRep={category.crowdScore} reps={category.reps} includeReps={includeReps} />;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

Each table row looks like this:

```
var CategoriesItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var reps = this.props.includeReps ? <td>{this.props.reps}</td> : '';

    return (
      <tr className="categoriesItem">
        <td>{this.props.category}</td>
        <td><ScoreBar directRep={this.props.directRep} prevDirectRep={this.props.prevDirectRep} category={this.props.category}/></td>
        <td>{this.props.crowdRep}</td>
        {reps}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

Why can I do to make React accept these table changes? When I start with the table with all four columns and then switch to a different user's profile page, the fourth table data piece becomes a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a hack, but giving a react component a key will force the entire component to re-render when the key changes. If each profile page gives the table a unique key, then this problem goes away.